# sdist and bdist_wheel freezes at build

Tags: python

I am trying to build a wheel and source distribution on windows 10 for a project of mine, but the build freezes at `removing 'release-exporter-1.0' (and everything under it)` for `sdist` and `creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\release_exporter-1.0.dist-info\WHEEL` for `bdist_wheel`.

Following is my `setup.py`

```
setup(
    name='release-exporter',
    version=version(),
    install_requires=get_requirements('requirements.txt'),
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='https://github.com/akshaybabloo/release-exporter',
    license='MIT',
    author='Akshay Raj Gollahalli',
    author_email='akshay@gollahalli.com',
    description='Release exporter for GitHub and GitLab.',
    keywords="changelog releases",
    classifiers=[
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Topic :: Utilities'
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'rex = release_exporter:main'
        ]
    },
)
```

I have tried to manually give the package name from `['release_exporter']` to using `find_packages()` of setup tools. I also thought the `keyword` should be a string, so I changed it from `['changelog', 'releases']` to `"changelog releases"`. But still no luck.

Also, I have tried to set `--verbose` flag by doing `python setup.py sdist --verbose`, but it doesn't work. I think the bug is not rectified yet -> https://bugs.python.org/issue7202

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I am using `Python 3.6.3`

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in `Python 3.6.3` -> https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/changelog.html#build. Just in case if anyone has a problem, update your Python to `Python 3.4.4`.